# Parse of ${index.loop} from JSP is failing "Cannot parse null string"

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I've made a Cart and the orders is printing out fine, now I add the feature of removing items. A button is made that should be parsing the indexnumber from my loop and on to my servlet and activate my removeFromCart method. But even though I parse other numbers on the my servlet just fine, this one is giving me an error:

**Message** Cannot parse null string
**Description** The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
**Exception** java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string

**NOTE that it is only the four lines with // that is causing me this error**

My Button

```
 <jsp:body>
        <form action="addtocart" method="post">
            Bottom:
            <select name="bottom" id="bottom">
                <option value="1">Chokolade (5 kr)</option>
                <option value="2">Vanilje (6 kr)</option>
                <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="4">Audi</option>
            </select>
            Topping:
            <select name="top" id="top">
                <option value="1">Chokolade (10 kr)</option>
                <option value="2">Vanilje (6 kr)</option>
                <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="4">Audi</option>
            </select>
            Quantity:
            <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <button name="addToCart"> Add to Cart</button>
        </form>

        Order lines: ${requestScope.cartsize}<br>
        Cart is having:<br>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${sessionScope.cart.cupcakeList}" varStatus="loop">
           <form action="addtocart" method="post"> 
    Quantity ${item.quantity} Order line number: ${loop.index+1} 
    <button name="removeFromCart" value="${loop.index}"type="submit">Remove from Cart
    </button></form><br>
        </c:forEach>
</jsp:body>
```

And this is from my doGet

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute("cart");

        int topId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("top"));
        int bottomId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("bottom"));
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity"));
    //  int removeFromCart = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("removeFromCart"));


        Top top = CupcakeFacade.getTopById(topId);
        Bottom bottom = CupcakeFacade.getBottomById(bottomId);

        Cupcake cupcake = new Cupcake(top, bottom, quantity);

        cart.addToCart(cupcake);
        session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        request.setAttribute("cartsize", cart.getNumberOfCupcakes());

   //   if(removeFromCart >= 0){
   //     cart.removeFromCart(removeFromCart);
   //   }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Submit buttons don't get submitted as parameters. That is, why you can't get it with `request.getParameter` and why it is null. Or have I missed, where you have a form input with the same name?

Comment: to avoid people going to a wrong direction, you might want to include the foreach wrapping the form/button definition
Also if you could clarify which line raised the "java.lang.NumberFormatException" it could be useful


Assuming the addtocart entrypoint is correctly mapping to your doPost method, where do you expect the top/bottom/quantity parameters to come from? It's not clear that your form is providing any of those

Last: the javascript tag is questionable on this issue

Comment: @Geshode - Hmm, I don't have a form input but above this I have a forEach where I run my array with items and thereby getting my loop.index numbers I use as a parameter I try to parse on to my servlet.

Comment: @user3252327 - I'have now added forEach and one of the dropdown menu's that is working correct for me.

Comment: could you update the question with the full form within the foreach? Basically what will be sent as parameters are the inputs in your form. Right now, your form contains nothing except the button itself and perhaps the quantity that I assume is not declared outside the for loop (if it's actually outside, even the quantity will be null) => this could lead to all the parseInt to throw exceptions since the parameters would be null

Comment: OP said, that `int removeFromCart = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("removeFromCart"));` causes the problem. And that is, because there is no parameter send with the name "removeFromCart", because that is the name of the submit button and submit buttons are not send as parameters.

Comment: @user3252327 - I don't think you are reading my question correct. Everything beside the four lines with // to the left is working correct, this means the parameters with top, bottom and quantity doesn't matter in this occasion. It is just posted to give the whole thing meaning, as that part is working for me with parsing on values but my buttons isn't.

Comment: @Geshode - I'm not sure exactly what you mean here, are you saying I can't parse any values with a button? I think it sounds weird if I can't, but I don't know.

Comment: @Gehode then the solution is to add a hidden input named removeFromCart in the form within the foreach with the value as the index

Comment: @Narj I am saying, that the submit button is not send as a parameter in the form data. So, there is no "removeFromCart" parameter on your server side in the request.

Comment: Something like:
<c:forEach var="item" items="${sessionScope.cart.cupcakeList}" varStatus="loop">
           <form action="addtocart" method="post"> 
    Quantity ${item.quantity} Order line number: ${loop.index+1} <input type="hidden" name="removeFromCart" value="${loop.index}" />
    <button type="submit">Remove from Cart
    </button></form><br>
        </c:forEach>

Comment: Thank you for your input but this does not seem to be working either. It keeps interacting with other actions. (Error when I try to Add to Cart) but my payload is being sent.